# UIPageViewConrtoller or Scroll View

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I'm a student dev and I'm making an app for my school and I wanted to see how to implement the user scrolling through the cards in my app in a single view, and I wanted to know what would be better to implement by using a UIScrollView or a PageViewController? I have added my prototype designs to give you a better idea of what I'm talking about. Thanks guys!

[Home Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWFhn.png)

[Home Screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWFhn.png)

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWFhn.png): [image]

Comment: what about collectionview ????

Comment: Totally agree with @EICaptainv2.0. You could even look into something like iCarousel : https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into iCarousel it looks interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Collection View and table view which is very easy to handle if there are more content to show.
Scroll view and page controller are the secondary component to show content in scrolable fashion